# Definite Integration involving Error function from 0 to infinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I am trying to integrate the following:

$y=\int_0^\infty x\left(Erf[\frac{x-a}{c}]-Erf[\frac{x-b}{c}]\right)dx$

Here a,b, c can take only positive real numbers.

However, in Mathematica, I don't get any result. Rather, I get the same expression as the output.
But, on substituting a,b and c with some positive real numbers , I get a definite value.
I think it's possible to get the result even in the terms of a,b, and c but I have no idea. Please help!

My code goes like (Sorry,I am new to Mathematica!):

In[1]:= y = x (Erf[(x - a)/c] - Erf[(x - b)/c])

Integrate[y, {x, 0, Infinity}]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add Mathematica code that you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @Syed Thanks! I have put it up, now.

Comment: @Nasser I am using v 13.0 and i think you are using erfc instead of erf

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk same here! I see erfc in your code

Comment: Using **erf** not **erfc** v 13.1 give me:`-(a^2/2) + b^2/2 - (a c E^(-(a^2/c^2)))/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) + (
 b c E^(-(b^2/c^2)))/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) - 1/2 a^2 Erf[a/c] - 
 1/4 c^2 Erf[a/c] + 1/2 b^2 Erf[b/c] + 1/4 c^2 Erf[b/c]`

Comment: @Nasser Oh sorry! got mixed up because of the other comments.

Comment: @Nasser, you are using `(f-a)` and `(f-b)`? I am getting the same output as @MariuszIwaniuk above.

Comment: My code is: y = x (Erf[(x - a)/c] - Erf[(x - b)/c]) and then Integrate[y, {x, 0, Infinity}]

Comment: @Syed opps, you are right. That what happens when trying to type something from an image :)  No wonder I was getting zero.  Ok, will delete my comment in this case.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the plain text code there as it will be easier to see than in comments.

Comment: `y1 = Assuming[{a, b, c} \[Element] PositiveReals, 
   Integrate[integrand, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
   ] // Expand` where `integrand = x (Erf[(x - a)/c] - Erf[(x - b)/c])`. Please edit properly. Your $\LaTeX$ does not match your code so far.

Comment: Thanks @Syed ... I just had to write the assumption